# Dynamically creating GridViewItem XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, grid

I have a list that will not always have the same number of objects in it, could be 1, 10, 15, etc. Right now I am just guessing and placing that guessed amount of `GridviewItems` in my `XAML`. I want to dynamically build the `GridviewItems` based on the amount of objects in my list. I have have this in a loop of course, I am just unsure of how to do this in `c#`. I will show you the XAML I have right now that is not dynamically creating the `GridviewItems`.

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <controls:PageHeader BackButtonVisibility="Collapsed" Content="News" Frame="{x:Bind Frame}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:EllipsisBehavior Visibility="Auto" />
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
            <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
        </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
    </controls:PageHeader>

    <GridView Margin="12,60" ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="#2A2A2A" Margin="5" Height="200" Width="300">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

**Web Service**

```
[OperationContract]
List<ViewDetails> ViewDetails();

[DataContract]
public class ViewDetails
{
    public string TitleView { get; set; }
    public string BodyView { get; set; }
    public string AuthorView { get; set; }

    public ViewDetails() { }
    public ViewDetails(string myTitleView, string myBodyView, string myAuthorView)
    {
        this.TitleView = myTitleView;
        this.BodyView = myBodyView;
        this.AuthorView = myAuthorView;
    }
}

 public List<ViewDetails> ViewDetails()
    {
        List<ViewDetails> details = new List<ViewDetails>();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 [My_Title] AS 'Title', [My_Body] AS 'Body', [My_Author] AS 'Author' FROM [My_table] ORDER BY [Date] DESC", conn);
        SqlDataReader rdrDetails = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            while (rdrDetails.Read())
            {
                details.Add(new ViewDetails(rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Title")).ToString(), rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Body")).ToString(), rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Author")).ToString()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //exception
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return details;
    }
```

**Project where I am calling web service**

```
 public async void ViewData()
 {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        string title = string.Empty;
        string body = string.Empty;
        string author = string.Empty;

        var res = await client.ViewDetailsAsync();
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
        {
           myList.Add(new GetDetails(res[i].TitleView, res[i].BodyView, res[i].AuthorView));
        }
  }

   public class GetDetails
    {
        public string TitleView { get; set; }
        public string BodyView { get; set; }
        public string AuthorView { get; set; }

        public GetDetails() { }
        public GetDetails(string titleView, string bodyView, string authorView)
        {
            this.TitleView = titleView;
            this.BodyView = bodyView;
            this.AuthorView = authorView;
        }
    }
```

What I am looking for is some way to programatically build the `GridViewItems`... Any suggestions?

Comment: Usually we create an `ObservableCollection` and feed it as the `ItemsSource` of GridView. Adding and removing the items from the collection will be reflected in the `GridView`.

Comment: Can you post an example of how I can create an ObservableCollection via returned list from web service? And how I would reflect the adding of items in the GridView? I will post my Web Service above for reference of what I have if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind `ItemsSource`

```
    <GridView Margin="12,60" ItemsSource={Binding ItemsList}>
...
    </GridView>
```

EDIT:

1) You can use DataGrid like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestDataCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding TitleView}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Body" Binding="{Binding BodyView}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Author" Binding="{Binding AuthorView}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

2) Or ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TestDataCollection}">
      <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Author" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AuthorView}"/>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TitleView}"/>
          </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

3) Or ListBox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestDataCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AuthorView}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleView}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: How would this dynamically create the gridviews(tiles)?

Comment: @Code For each item in ItemsList will created ListViewItem

Comment: I made your corrections, but am getting no grid views being built... I have edited my question with update code of how I am building my list and binding it in my gridview.. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to amend the situation by giving my gridview a name and doing this in my code behind: myGridView.ItemsSource = myList;

Comment: My question that follows that though, is now that I am building the gridview item, how can I place the data in the item? Before I was building my gridviewitems manually and each item had 4 textblocks in them, with a specific peice of information going into each block (i.e. Title, Body, Author, Date). How is this possible with the way I am binding list to itemsource?

Comment: @Code 1) You can use DataGrid instead GridView, so in this case you can define columns, bind columns to Title, Body, Author and Date. 2) You can define GridView`s ItemTemplate as you want

Comment: Can you look at my updated question and post a code snippet of your suggestion there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920968/adding-textblock-to-gridviewitem-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment55603595_33920968

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96177/discussion-between-code-and-galakt).

Comment: @Code Mark answer as solution if it helped you and create new questions  in new separated posts

Comment: Thank you for all of your help